# Can stock brokerage firms fail?

Tags: brokerage, sipc

Can brokerage firms like Fidelity, TD Ameritrade, or Vanguard fail? They seem pretty unshakable, but the recent financial crisis made it clear that even very large financial companies can fall. And over the timescale of my lifetime, it seems very possible that one could go out of business.

- What would happen in that case to investments I made through that company?
- Would I lose my money?
- What about IRAs?

Comment: Google MF Global, you should get your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brokerages are supposed to keep your money separate from theirs. So, even if they fail as a company, your money and investments are still there, and can be transferred to another brokerage. It doesn't matter if it's an IRA or taxable account.

Of course, as is the case with MF Global, if illegally take their client's money (i.e., steal), it may be a different story. In such cases, SIPC covers up to $500K, of which $250K can be cash, as JoeTaxpayer said.

You may be interested in the following news item from the SEC. It's about some proposed changes, but to frame the proposal they lay out the way it is now:
http://www.sec.gov/news/press/2011/2011-128.htm

The most relevant quote:

> The Customer Protection Rule (Rule 15c3-3).
>   This SEC rule requires a
>   broker-dealer to segregate customer securities and cash from the
>   firm’s proprietary business activities. If the broker-dealer fails,
>   these customer assets should be readily available to be returned to
>   customers.

Comment: Great answer, but note that the rules listed here only cover the U.S.

Comment: +1 for not putting your personal agenda in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any company can go under. [SIPC](http://www.sipc.org/How/Brochure.aspx) offers a level of protection. They don't guarantee against stocks dropping, but will replace stocks that you owned, but the broker stole from you. (overgeneralization).
There's a $500K limit, with $250K max in cash.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the entire financial system is based on trust. As we have seen repeatedly, even the ratings agencies can be wrong and in collusion.

You need to understand what products have any insurance/contingency/recourse if things don't go as planned. A lot of people were surprised when they found out SIPC didn't ensure futures when MF Global declared bankruptcy last fall.

Comment: What trust has to do with anything? Has anyone trusted lied to these surprised people?

Comment: those were two separate paragraphs and thoughts littleadv. trust has to do with trusting what the ratings agencies say despite their checkered past, trusting that the SIPC will make good on their protection, trusting that a brokerage firm complies with self regulatory bodies. despite "checks and balances" there is a degree of trust involved, trusting that you or your financial advisor understands what products you are getting into.

Comment: @littleadv you might find this quote from the article I linked to in my answer interesting: -- “When investors hand their assets over to a broker-dealer, they trust that their broker-dealer will hold and invest the assets as directed,” said SEC Chairman Mary L. Schapiro. --

Comment: @Patches - they trust that the broker won't break the law. When I meet people on a street I trust them not to kill me, but it doesn't mean that I have a relationship based on trust with them, it means that I have a relationship based on law with them. I believe saying "financial system is based on trust" is plain **wrong**, even if you find me a quote of someone saying it. Financial system is based on **law**. If someone does something that is legal, you cannot "trust" them to do it in **your** best interest, it will be in **their** best interest. If you think otherwise - you're a fool.

Comment: littleadv, the law does not cover things that are not expressly prohibited, and with new products being made every day there is a great degree of trust involved in how all counterparties will react to the performance of a product or service. Also JP Morgan said it himself.

Comment: @littleadv the law creates the trust. In this case, that your broker won't raid your account. Contract law creates trust that the counterparty will hold up their end of the deal. Trust is the key to a strong currency, and so on. All these things enable the immense movement & application of capital that's possible today, and in turn out high standard of living. How to create and foster trust is a key point of study in economics. That said, I do agree that this answer is too general, or perhaps academic, and doesn't address the question sufficiently.

Comment: @CQM while it is true that certain new instruments, like CDS'es, fell through the regulatory cracks for a few years, the things the poster was asking about - brokerage accounts - and the products offered at the companies he referenced - like Vanguard - all have a long history, are well understood, and thoroughly regulated.

Comment: @Patches - then you can reduce everything to trust. the law doesn't create trust, the law creates penalties and compensations that ultimately are expected to lead to deterrence. I think there's a fundamental difference between that and simple trust.

Comment: @littleadv if you only look at actions, good or bad, after they've been taken, then yes. The trust thing is about what happens in the future, and the things it enables when it exists. Take for instance, writing a check, say to your mortgage lender. That lender will take your check because they can trust that little piece of paper, and what you wrote on it, will be honored at another bank and they will receive their money. If they didn't trust it, they wouldn't take it, and you wouldn't have the option of that efficient, secure way of transferring large amounts of money.

Comment: @Patches - I disagree. they don't care and definitely don't trust me. I'm not sure anyone actually touches that piece of paper other than the minimum wage employee in the mail room. If it bounces - it will be my problem, not theirs. There's no trust here.

Comment: @littleadv the fact that they don't have to care is the trust. If there was no enforcement mechanism against bouncing a check, and if people therefore regularly bounced checks (note both have to be true), then they would not take your check. No one would take anyone's check, and checks, as a system, would cease to exist. Your only option then would be to go through the hassle and risk of carrying large amounts of cash around. You don't have to now because they trust the check and the checking system.

Comment: @Patches so its not trust, its the assurance of the law then, right? To quote you: *"If there was no enforcement mechanism against bouncing a check"* - but there is, so noone needs to trust anyone. By the way, checks as a system ceased to exist a long time ago anywhere else but the US. We're retarded, and still use these stupid pieces of paper for some reason. But then again, only in the US being conservative is something people take pride in...

Comment: @littleadv Law is used to help create an environment of trust, yes. You can learn a little more about the study of trust in economics at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_%28social_sciences%29#Economics

Comment: @Patches I'm not a big fan of social sciences. I believe that while in general there's amount of trust in financial transactions, it is not what makes us chose one broker or the other. Its the laws and regulations and our trust *in the law enforcement* to enforce them. That trust is back up by our ability to vote out those who break it.

Comment: you trust that the brokerage isn't overleveraged, you trust that their accounts are segregated in compliance with all regulations. those are just examples ie. Nobody knew that Morgan Stanley was leveraged 40:1 in 2007